# Set Height of ListView at run time in android

Tags: android, listview

How to set Height of ListView.

XML Code (This code is working fine and fixed height as 200 dip)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_ListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="5dip"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent" />        
</LinearLayout>
```

Android Code (This code not fixed width and height)

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.dialog_page, null );
convertView.setLayoutParams( new ListView.LayoutParams( 200, 300) );
```

Android Code (This code i got Error Message)

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.lock_file_page, parent );
convertView.setLayoutParams( new ListView.LayoutParams( 200, 300) );
```

Error Message

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

How do fix Width and Height at Runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try This code..

```
 LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) mListView.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = 300;
 mListView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =  (LayoutParams) mListview.getLayoutParams();` add this to work fine.

Comment: Sorry , I don't know about ios.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Giving a short description what you did and why along with your code would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

First Remove import files for LayoutParams and after that Use below code for LayoutParams.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 300);
convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This code not working. I got same error message `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams`

Comment: @user1474868 please post your full code with import statements, so i will give you proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void setDynamicHeight(ListView listView) {
ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
    return;
    }
int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

    if(listItem != null){
        listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

    }
}
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
listView.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.requestLayout();}
```