# how to set height of list that embedded in other list in Android

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I write the AndroidApp that show posts and comments 
to the user like any social group!I have list of post and in 
each postItem I have list of comment but I can't 
set size of commentlist !

I try:
[Set Height of ListView at run time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465833/set-height-of-listview-at-run-time-in-android[1])
&&
[Set ListView item height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439401/set-listview-item-height[2])
but not work!

the customList for post:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post,null,true);
    ...
    //view commentslist
        if (cp.size() > 0) {
        if (cp.get(String.valueOf(position)) != null) {
            commentList adapter = new commentList(context, cp.get(String
                    .valueOf(position)));
            ListView list = (ListView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listviewComment);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```

the customlist for commentList:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment,null, true);
    TextView txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextComment);
    txt.setText(web.get(position), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    return rowView;
}
```

then I add to customList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    View listItem = adapter.getView(i,null,list);
                    listItem.measure(0,0);
                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = list.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = totalHeight;
                list.setLayoutParams(params);
               list.requestLayout();
 }
}
```

but not work! and the commentlist fill all parent!and can't view other posts!

then I try to change commentlist inflate to

```
 View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment,parent,false);
```

but only view one comment!!!!!!!
please help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: embedded listviews is kinda tricky, you'll want to have a scrollview instead imho for comments

Comment: Please explain why those posts didn't help you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman in "Set ListView item height" post only can view one comment!not all list of item!